# Get current URL from document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to parse my URL in document.ready() so that I can get the id of the current page and dynamically populate the page with results from an AJAX call. The problem I am running into is due to the fact that I think that 'document.URL' references the previous page until 'document.ready()' has fully executed.

How do I get around this? I have researched document.load(), and auto-refreshing the page once, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I have been working on this since yesterday.

Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var id = document.URL.substring(document.URL.lastIndexOf('?')+4);
    if(!loadObject.executed) {
        loadObject(id);
        loadObject.executed = true;
    } else {
    $('#page-full').on('pagecreate', loadObject(id));
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried using a small `setTimeout`? And BTW, instead, you could take a closer look to window.popstate and pushstate for your dynamic AJAX History manipulation

Comment: location.search could be an alternative

Comment: That should not be a restriction with `document.URL`, how would it be aware of the last page? Are you sure the URL is incorrect?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I am sure that the URL is incorrect. I am logging it to the console in "loadObject" and it prints out the URL I came from. 
Others: I am researching the alternatives you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I would swap it for an alert() to make sure the console is lot lazy-loading something

Comment: Already did that, it is giving me the URL I am coming from.

Comment: Same for `window.location.href` ?

Comment: I am able to get the URL, and I have already tried both document.URL and window.location. But since I am asking for URL inside of document.ready (because I want the call to be made as the page is loading), it is giving me the URL of the previous page.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Could you post your solution as an answer so I can check it? Instead of putting the call to loadObject in document.ready, I put:
setTimeout(loadObject, 0); at the top of my js page, and declared the variable id inside of loadObject. Problem solved, or at least patched for now.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use document.location.href instead of document.URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this and still produced the same bug. The funny thing is that I had a friend try it on his computer, and he couldnt produce the same bug. I ended up calling the function in setTimeout(loadObject, 0) and it went away. Thanks for your help.